# chat source code

Tags: source, chat-command

Is the source code of `chat` program (used for dialog with modem) open? If it is so, where can I find it? I've been trying find it, but no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source: `git://git.ozlabs.org/~paulus/ppp.git`
Homepage: http://ppp.samba.org/

How to find it yourself next time:

- Find the package containing the command. On Debian and its derivatives e.g.

  ```
  dpkg -S /full/path/to/chat` or `apt-file search bin/chat`
  ```
- If necessary, find a more detailed description of the program, e.g.

  ```
  apt-cache show ppp
  ```
- Feed your favourite search engine with *homepage [packagename | Description]*

Comment: `apt-file` does not require the full path. `bin/chat` is perfectly fine if one does not know whether the binary is located in `/usr/bin/`, `/sbin/`, `/usr/sbin/`, etc.